AWS Lambda python log file is not created
I have a Python AWS lambda with a logger that generates two different log files:
LOG = f"/tmp/{uuid.uuid1()}_log.log"
SLOW_LOG = f"/tmp/{uuid.uuid1()}_slow.log"

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                    format="%(levelname)s - %(message)s",
                    handlers=[logging.FileHandler(LOG),
                    logging.StreamHandler()])

slow_logger = logging.getLogger("slow_requests")
slow_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
file_handler = logging.FileHandler(SLOW_LOG)
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(levelname)s - %(message)s")
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
slow_logger.addHandler(file_handler)
slow_logger.propagate = False

When the code was executed from command line, it created the two different logs and I had no issue. However, when I implemented it as a Lambda, LOG is created empty while SLOW_LOG is fine. I've been loosing my mind over this... can anyone help?

Lambda already calls basicConfig() when loading the module, so your second call has no effect. You'll need to manually reconfigure the root logger.

And FYI, the lambda tag isn't appropriate for AWS Lambda -- as noted in the tag description.
